# Movement through a timer

Tags: java, swing, timer

I am trying to make several small boxes move around a page based on several properties. The movement itself is handled by the method private void direction_move_creature(){. which i then call in as:

```
public class Listener implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        //Looping 200 time steps, each time updating the coordinates of the creatures.
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            direction_move_creature();
            repaint();
        }
        System.out.println("HERE");
    }
}
```

and my main method is:

```
  public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Draw");
    frame.setSize(550, 550);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(new Draw());
    frame.setVisible(true);
    System.out.println("final");
  }
}
```

new Draw just fills the structures that hold the coordinates for the moving shapes. When i try to run the program i get no movement what so ever. I knwo these are only fragments of code but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try and think of Swing `Timer`s like a pseudo loop, basically, each time the `actionPerformed` method is called is another run through the loop

Answer (score 4):

You're misunderstanding how a Swing Timer works. The Timer **replaces** the for loop. Get rid of the loop and increment a counter within the timer's ActionListener.

e.g.,

```
class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {
    private int counter = 0;

    @Override        
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // assuming MAX_COUNTER is 20
        if (counter < MAX_COUNTER) {
            direction_move_creature();
            repaint(); 
            counter++;
        } else {
            // stop the Timer
            ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. so would the action method look like this:

Comment: @Sam: see edit, and don't post code in comments please. Also note that your main method that you posted was singularly non-helpful and had code completely unrelated to the problem at hand. Just FYI.